# Wiki that can be integrated into a web-application

Tags: web-applications, licensing, integration, wiki, mediawiki-api

I've been thinking about integrating a wiki into my web-application. Currently I'm testing MediaWiki API (web-services interface), but my intended usage will most likely conflict with the GPL license. Some parts of my web-application is closed source.

Does anyone have good experiences or recommendations for a Wiki (with BSD-license or similar) that have a web-services interface that will allow me to retrieve/create articles (both formated and raw text) and supports userrights-management.

Comment: I'm not sure whether they are actually compliant with GPL (see [some recent discussions on GPL vs. AGPL for MediaWiki](http://markmail.org/search/?q=AGPL%20list%3Aorg.wikimedia)), but there's many websites using MediaWiki together with unfree plugins. Do you need to distribute the resulting combination, or is it just for yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Home/?language=en) too, as I know it's a quite good and evolving wiki applicaiton.
I am not sure about the Web services links, but there is quite complete [document for developers](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/DevGuide/) to use and communique with XWiki.

Edit: I forgot to say that XWiki is under LGPL Open-source licence.

Answer (score 1):

It's commercial, but [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) by Atlassian has a [good API](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Remote+API+Specification).